# Language packs for an MVC3 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a website structure which will allow for multiple "language packs" for verbiage across the site.

I have look into internationalization, but I'm not sure it's the route will work because all the different language packs will be in English. It would just be re-wordings, essentially.

Can internationalization (with resource files) work for this, or is there a better option out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internationalization should work because it does factor in locale. Even if the language is the same, the locale is different. Eg en-gb

Take a look at this post. Note the section where the post talks about the differences between spanish in mexico and spanish in spain.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

Comment: It would not be for different locales, however. It would be used for different websites/themes using the same package. There could be 10 different language files, each using "en-us". And to further complicate it, in theory each one of those sites could allow spanish as well, resulting in 10 en-us and 10 sp files.